# Writing a DVD demuxer using ffmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a demuxer for DVD under FFmpeg.I understand that I need to accomplish something like:

```
./ffmpeg -i foo.iso foo.mkv
```

I was told to use libdvdread to extract the things from the ripped file.How exactly should I start with the demuxer? I am clueless and I can't find any documentation on using `libdvdread`. It'd be great if someone could explain how to accomplish sending stream of audio,video and subtitles to their respective decoders.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the demuxer, you don't need to worry about sending packets to their respective decoders themselves, ffmpeg takes care of that for you. What you do need to do is correctly declare the codecs/formats of each stream on the dvd in your read_header function (which will no doubt require calling some initialization in libdvdread to find the main feature on the dvd or have your demuxer take some arguments as to which feature/chapter to start reading from) and then each time read_packet is called you can provide a single packet of data (eg some subtitle, some audio, some video read using libdvdread) along with which stream it corresponds to and ffmpeg handles it from there.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Any idea on where I could get a proper documentation on libdvdread? I tried searching for it but couldn't find one.